# Having trouble implementing namespaces in XML

Tags: xml, namespaces

Within the code below I am receiving an error  at "7.65GB", it keeps telling me "The prefix "UMUC2" for element "UMUC2:size" is not bound". Everything looks correct cannot figure out the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- New document created with EditiX at Sat Jul 05 07:35:36 AST 2014 -->

<dataCollection xmlns:UMUC1="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/games">
xmlns:UMUC2="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/software">
xmlns:UMUC3="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/music">
xmlns:UMUC4="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/video">
    <UMUC1:size>17.5GB</UMUC1:size>
    <UMUC1:date_of_collection>01/01/2013</UMUC1:date_of_collection>
    <UMUC1:collectionSite>www.google.com</UMUC1:collectionSite>
    <UMUC2:size>7.65GB</UMUC2:size>
    <UMUC2:date_of_collection>05/28/2013</UMUC2:date_of_collection>
    <UMUC2:collectionSite>www.microsoft.com</UMUC2:collectionSite>
    <UMUC3:size>100.5GB</UMUC3:size>
    <UMUC3:date_of_collection>06/26/2013</UMUC3:date_of_collection>
    <UMUC3:collectionSite>www.apple.com</UMUC3:collectionSite>
    <UMUC4:size>1.75TB</UMUC4:size>
    <UMUC4:date_of_collection>03/27/2014</UMUC4:date_of_collection>
    <UMUC4:collectionSite>www.videox.com</UMUC4:collectionSite>
</dataCollection>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XML, the declarations for the `UMUC2`, `UMUC3`, and `UMUC4` prefixes are not correct; they are interpreted as element content.

The namespace declarations on the root element must look like this (note the removed right angle brackets):

```
<dataCollection xmlns:UMUC1="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/games"
                xmlns:UMUC2="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/software"
                xmlns:UMUC3="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/music"
                xmlns:UMUC4="http://umuc.edu/namespaces/video">
```